# How can I set innerHTML of an Element in Polymer 3?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

In my template string I have a p tag. How can I set its innerHTML with a variable?

Lets say

```
Let myVar = ”<b>Hello</b> there”;
<p id=”myPara”>${myVar}</p>
```

When I wrap myVar inside the p tag, the html format does’t actually work

```
<p>${myVar}</p>
```

Comment: This ${myVar} variable is inside p tag. Actuall myVar has ”<b>Hello</b> World”. I want text to HTML support. I can achieve this by setting the innerHTML if p tag. But how can I set innerHTML of p tag in templete string?

Comment: Have you tried removing the html tag in your template() method? Example: `return \`<p>${htmlBlockGoesHere}</p>\`;` However I'm not really sure why would you want to do this instead of binding properties in your template.

Answer (score 4):

> Actuall myVar has `”<b>Hello</b> World”`. I want text to HTML support.

Important information above.

This is kind of a cheat, but all elements in HTML got an innerHTML property.

Try

```
<p id=”myPara” inner-h-t-m-l="${myVar}"></p>
```

Comment: inner-h-t-m-l is the key

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer/issues/366) on polymer-modulizer official repo. It might be related to this, in Polymer 2 template [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template):

> To protect against XSS vulnerabilities, Polymer.html only interpolates HTMLTemplateElement values. Non-template values will throw an error.

I'm not certain on how to solve this, but it seems that you already try to hard-code the innerHTML, why not go ahead and use either properties binding or just hard-coded HTML like this?:

`<p id=”myPara”><b>Hello</b> there</p>`

What is your specific reason for using variables in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use appendchild to insert the content in the p tag.

```
let instance = this.$.myPara;
instance.appendChild('your markup');
```